# Dependancy injection : injecting a single class from a large assembly

Tags: c#, debugging, dependency-injection

To preface this, it is ultimately likely that we will end up injecting the majority of classes implemented in the assembly but for the purpose of this question I am only interested in a single class.

A colleague is in the process of implementing a new service following a clean architecture pattern and we were discussing the initial solution/project layout. I noted that there were a number of projects that were not sat under the infrastructure project although they were responsible for dealing with calling external APIs. In my mind, unless we get to a level of complexity that dictates splitting these into separate projects, then infrastructure code should remain in a single project. There were 2 additional projects that each contained a single class which implemented the interface defined in core.

The only argument that he provided that I felt might have some influence was on the subject of DI. The comment he made was that if the class was contained within a large assembly then there would be an increased overhead injecting that class into whatever process needed it when compared to loading the same class from an assembly that only contained that class.

Essential, what I am looking to understand is that if Assembly A contained classes A,B,C and D and I only injected class A, would the whole assembly be loaded before instantiating class A.

This got me thinking as to whether that was a valid argument or potentially while a valid point, the overhead as so negligible that you might as well ignore it.

How could I demonstrate what the difference, if any, is between the 2 scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You only want to include what should be included and nothing more, you don't ever want to include an entire assembly just because you wanted to use a single class or a couple of functions.

This will not only violate things like single responsibility and the concept of modularity, but it will cause you many more issues down the line if you start doing things like this.  Right now it might seem like a small overhead if it's "just one class in just two projects", but that quickly becomes 10 classes in 4 projects with 100 dependencies.

I'm not exactly clear on what you're specifically trying to do but any project/service/module/component/class should import and include only what's needed for its own functionality and nothing more.  If you're using DI it should inject the exact resource that's required, nothing more.  There are very few edge case scenarios where that rule can be broken, i.e. if it causes significant company costs or if there's some other valid reason for violating it.

(I don't know how your assembly libraries work so my answer is purely based on general design.)

Comment: I get that, but I am looking to understand that if I inject class A from Assembly A, but Assembly A also contains classes B,C and D (but these are not required in this scenario and therefore not injected by DI) would the whole assembly be in scope or just class A?

Comment: Oh I understand.  I don't know enough about c# to answer that.  However I'd say that the assembly itself should contain stuff that's relevant to it, loading it into memory then only to use one of those things is okay.  The assembly itself should be single responsibility, so it shouldn't ever be so big that it's a problem if you need to load it into memory to use a single resource from it.  That being said if we're only talking about 3-4 classes then it really doesn't matter, those microseconds or kilobytes aren't going to affect anything.  Whether it's including the entire assembly, no clue.